# Entity not posted back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Here's the controller method that calls the view:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? paramid)
        {
            var document = documentRepository.DocumentsWithEmpty.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == paramid.Value);
            RC rc = new RC(document);
            return View("RC", rc);
        }
```

Here's the view (pretty empty for the moment)

```
@model RC

@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm()) //I've also tried by specifying the method/controller/param
{
   //I've also tried with some @Html.EditorFor items
}
```

And the method in the controller to catch the posted `RC`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(RC rc) //If I put no parameter, it gets called correctly
{
    throw new Exception("x");
}
```

It is the only entity/place where it doesn't work correctly. Could it be because RC isn't an entity in my database?

Firebug points these for both the GET and POST requests (with the POST request in red). Pretty straightforward

```
http://localhost:58136/Documents/Edit/23?_=1351197746968
```

Comment: can you show your view, where the RC is bound?

Comment: How is the form being submitted?

Comment: try Edit(formcollection fm) and see what value keys are being returned.

Comment: might be worth testing your routes

Comment: Are you actually putting text boxes or other input fields in your using(Html.BeginForm()){} statement?  If you do not have any input fields defined, nothing will be posted back to the server as there are no form fields to post back...

Comment: What do you mean by the comment "If I put no parameter, it gets called correctly"? what happens when you have the parameter, is there and error?

Comment: @Rob Nothing happens, it's like the controller method is not found!

Comment: @AmmarAhmed With FormCollection, all works fine. I may just use that alternative if I can't figure it out

Comment: I am glad it works. I still think that you should find the cause for the problem to learn from it. I think that the fields (e.g. @Html.EditorFor) are not mapping correctly to the model. Make sure that the fields are the same name as the variable name. I tend to go back to old HTML <input> if I can't find the cause.